# Spaces around apostrophe

Tags: wordpress

I am having a weird problem on my WordPress site and cannot find any information about this online. For some reason any time I use an apostrophe (also happens with quotation marks) there are random spaces put around it. This does not happen everywhere on the site but it is particularly prevalent in titles. Anybody know what could be causing this bug?
[image][image]

Cheers

Comment: I've not encountered that happening before, but it's probably coming from the particular theme you're using. There's possibly a `:before` and `:after` pseudo-element getting created with additional whitespace, or margins set on a custom class. Are you able to inspect the whitespace to find out exactly where it's coming from?

Comment: I am using a custom theme that I have made myself, I went into my css and removed any :before or :after elements, this did not solve the problem. I also manually inspected the html and retyped the text, if I enter an apostrophe this way the spacing issue is not created.

Comment: hi can  you share website link please ?

Comment: Thanks, but I have solved this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the font I was using "Microsoft Tai Le" was causing this issue, I am not sure why but once i changed to a different font the problem was fixed.